# Searching an RDF Graph for Partial Matches

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, sparql

How would I search an RDF database to find the segments of the graph that overlap the most with a sample graph?

For example, say my database stores the following arbitrary graphs:

```
entity1 [
    type "TOP" ;
    attr1 [
        attr11 [
            attr111 "apple" ;
        ] ;
        attr12 [
            attr121 "orange" ;
        ] ;
        attr13 [
            attr131 "banana" ;
        ] ;
    ] ;
    attr2 [
        attr21 [
            attr211 "falcon" ;
        ] ;
        attr22 [
            attr221 "pigeon" ;
        ] ;
        attr23 [
            attr231 "parrot" ;
        ] ;
    ] ;
] .
entity2 [
    type "TOP" ;
    attr11 [
        attr111 "apple" ;
    ] ;
    attr12 [
        attr121 "orange" ;
    ] ;
] .
entity3 [
    type "TOP" ;
    attr2 [
        attr_middle [
            attr21 [
                attr211 "falcon" ;
            ] ;
            attr22 [
                attr221 "pigeon" ;
            ] ;
            attr23 [
                attr231 "parrot" ;
            ] ;
        ] ;
    ] ;
] .
```

And now say I have the sample graph:

```
sample [
    type "TOP" ;
    attr11 [
        attr111 "apple" ;
    ] ;
    attr12 [
        attr121 "orange" ;
    ] ;
    attr13 [
        attr131 "banana" ;
    ] ;
    attr21 [
        attr211 "falcon" ;
    ] ;
    attr22 [
        attr221 "pigeon" ;
    ] ;
    attr23 [
        attr231 "parrot" ;
    ] ;
] .
```

Clearly, nothing in the database matches the sample perfectly, but each entity matches it partially, even if the comman triples exist at different levels in each graph.

How would I find the closest matches to the sample? In this case, I'd expect a query to return, sorted best match first, `[entity1, entity3, entity2]`.

I'm still a little new to RDF, so forgive me if my terminology is off. As I currently understand RDF databases, what I'm trying to do isn't typically how they're used. If I want to find the entities "containing" the relation attr111 = "apple" using a SPARQL query, I'd generally have to assume that relation is at a fixed location relative to each entity, wheras searching to triples at arbitrary locations relative to a "root" is much more difficult. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not that difficult but your SPARQL queries may become rather long to achieve this.  There is no need to assume a fixed root since you can use variables for the root as shown in my examples.  In the case where the root is fixed substitute the variable for a value.

**Note** - If the resulting query has no variables in it then it would be better phrased as an `ASK` query.  If you use a `SELECT` query and there are no variables you have no way to distinguish between a query results that matches and one that doesn't.  Whereas an `ASK` query returns either `true` or `false` depending on whether the `WHERE` clause matches

If your SPARQL processor supports SPARQL 1.1 then you can use property paths .e.g

```
SELECT * WHERE { ?s ex:predicate / ex:predicate / ex:predicate "value" }
```

If you only have SPARQL 1.0 then you have to state the match explicitly like so:

```
SELECT * WHERE
{
  ?s ex:predicate _:b1 .
  _:b1 ex:predicate _:b2 .
  _:b2 ex:predicate "value" .
}
```

Note that semantically these two forms are actually equivalent - the SPARQL 1.1 form is a nice syntactic shortcut for the SPARQL 1.0 form.

Obviously the larger the part of your Graph you want to match grows the larger your SPARQL query will get.